# MySQL - select results from a secondary table as a column in a primary table

Tags: mysql

I have a set of data consisting of two tables: table one is a set of unique items, and table two is a log of references that link the items in the first table together. For example:

Table one

```
+------------+--------------------+
|         id | name               |
+------------+--------------------+
|         1  | Item 1             |
|         2  | Item 2             |
|         3  | Item 3             |
|         4  | Item 4             |
|         5  | Item 5             |
+------------+--------------------+
```

Table two

```
+------------+--------------------+
|  item_1_id | item_2_id          |
+------------+--------------------+
|         1  | 2                  |
|         1  | 3                  |
|         1  | 5                  |
|         2  | 4                  |
|         2  | 5                  |
+------------+--------------------+
```

Is it possible to group the rows that are in table two, and display them in some sort of array/collection as a column in table one. So based on my example tables, I would hope to return something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
|         id | name      | results  |
+------------+-----------+----------+
|         1  | Item 1    | 2, 3, 5  |
|         2  | Item 2    | 1, 4, 5  |
|         3  | Item 3    | 1        |
|         4  | Item 4    | 2        |
|         5  | Item 5    | 1, 2     |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: [The manual for GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat for show the aggregated result and a select union for obtain both the related item for grouping

```
  select id, name, group_concat( item1)
  from table_one 
  left join 
  (select  item_1_id as item1, item_2_id  as item2  
  from table_two
  union  
  select  item_2_id , item_1_id    
  from table_two
  order by item1)  t1 ont1.item1 = table_one.id
  group by id, name
```